# Cancel SQL execution when browser cancels OData request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata

I am using OData v3 with ASP.net 4.6 MVC 5, Oracle 11g.

I execute an OData c3 query via Ajax to my App server.
Then, I execute this in javascript on the front end, before the previous request has finished.

`xhr.abort();`

It causes a cancellation of an OData request to the server.
It does not cause the related SQL to stop running.

I learned about CancellationTokens in ASP.NET, but it seems they are already being used. I am looking for the simplest way to accomplish cancellation of the related SQL when the abort method is called on the related Ajax call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772597/detecting-async-client-disconnect-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Ok no mention of doing this with OData, where I don't see active control of the query.

Comment: It seems this cannot be done.